# How to use PFX Task.Factory.StartNew for F# functions taking a parameter?

Tags: .net, f#

Using the *Programming F#* book, there's an example first given as serial:

```
let result1 = longTask1()
let result2= = LongTask2()
```

Then using the PFX it is given to be

```
Open System.Threading.Tasks

let taskBody = new Func<string>(longTask1)
let task = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(taskBody)

let result2 = longTask2()
let result1 = task.Result
```

However, in my case the function `readBlock` takes in a string `filePath` as argument and returns a `seq`. I tried like this

```
let taskBody = new System.Func<string, seq<_>>(readBlock)
let task = Task.Factory.StartNew<seq<_>>(taskBody.Invoke(filePath))
```

This is showing an error for the Task.Factory.StartNew portion - too many  arguments. So how to go about calling parameterized functions that return a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the book is quite obsolete. The book was written before the release of VS 2010, some parts of F# and PFX weren't settled yet.

Now you can write:

```
let task = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> readBlock(filePath))
```

The type checker will infer an appropriate type for `task`, and you can invoke `task.Result` to get results later on.

There is implicit conversion between closure and `System.Func<_, _>`, and using closure is more readable in this case.

Comment: thanks. works. Replaced taskBody() by name of function readBlock() and things are fine. didn't know about that book being obsolete tho...